# How to split large file to small files with prefix in Linux/Bash

Tags: linux, bash, split

I have a file in `Linux` called `test`. Now I want to split the `test` into say 10 small files.

The `test` file has more than 1000 table names. I want the small files to have equal no of lines, the last file might have the same no of table names or not.

What I want is can we add a prefix to the split files while invoking the `split` command in the `Linux` terminal.

`Sample:`

```
test_xaa test_xab test_xac and so on..............
```

Is this possible in Linux.

Comment: it's unclear, what does mean *the small files to have equal no of tables* ?

Comment: show the exemplary fragment of your test file which can be split into 2 chunks(in 2 files)

Comment: google `csplit`

Comment: I misread the question, initially, but I believe my updated answer is what you need.

Comment: @Active_user - Can you update the question to provide sample data... For example, it would be good to know if the records have a defined separator. If so take a look at `--seperator` split operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my question with the following statement

```
split -l $(($(wc -l < test.txt )/10 + 1)) test.txt test_x
```

With this I was able to get the desired result

Comment: If you are running `split` version `8.22` it supports `-n` which can replace `-l $(($(wc -l < test.txt )/10 + 1))`. The command will then be `split -n 10 test.txt test_x`.

Comment: @alvits No it can't that will break up lines.

Comment: @123 - you are right. I forgot to put `-n l/10`. It should be `split -n l/10 test.txt test_x`.

Comment: @alvits Also doesn't do the same thing, whilst that preserves full lines, it splits files on size not number of lines.

Comment: @123 - nice catch. It looks like only `-n r/10` comes close to the desired output. I know, you will say it doesn't work. But it does comes close to the solution posted.

Comment: @alvits even -n r/10 doesn't give result like my answer

Answer (score 0):

I would've sworn split did this on it's own, but to my surprise, it does not.

To get your prefix, try something like this:

```
for x in /path/to/your/x*; do 
    mv $x your_prefix_$x
done
```